# Cannot parse persistence unit from class path resource

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

so I have this problem in running my Spring WS app which implements JPA ( or should implement..) I have a problem with running a WS, it looks like my Spring context can't find file `persistence.xml` Which i am able to believe because i did not have generated `META-INF` folder in my template (which is Maven project template with `archetype org.springframework.ws`) I have created `META-INF` manually.

Here is the HTTP 500:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'caChainDao' defined in file [E:\STS\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\zz\wtpwebapps\FCAWSv4\WEB-INF\classes\pl\famoc\test\ws\db\dao\caChainDao.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse persistence unit from class path resource [persistence.xml]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here it is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />

</persistence>
```

here it is where i am looking for it

```
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml" />
```

and here it is path to this xml in my classpath:

`src/main/webapp/META-INF/persistence.xml`

Could anyone give me a hint what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your generated jar and war files. What's inside webapp will be stored in the war file. And the META-INF directory of a war file is not in the classpath of the webapp. Store the META-INF directory under src/main/resources, so that its ends up in the WEB-INF/classes directry of the webapp, or in the generated jar file stored in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: i will check it by morning now i do not have strengh to open again STS , thanks anyway JB Nizet:) does this part looks good?<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml" />

Comment: Any other way? I am kind of desperate because any tutorial i use result with this error...

Answer (score 2):

you add only * after classpath like:

```
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:persistence.xml" />
```